# Ruby modulo 3 with negative numbers is unintuitive

Tags: ruby, modulo

Ruby modulo rules with negative numbers are unclear.  In IRB:

```
-7 % 3 == 2
```

Should be `1`!
Why?

Comment: Nope. Should be either 2 or -1, but **never** 1.

Answer (score 11):

Because -7/3 is -3 under Ruby's integer division semantics.  3*-3 is -9, so that would leave a remainder of 2.

According to [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Numeric.html#method-i-25), x modulo y is defined as:

```
x-y*(x/y).floor
```

Answer (score 10):

When one of the operands to `%` is negative, there’s no clear best answer
for what result to return. Every programming language has its own rules.
The Wikipedia page for [Modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) has a giant table of how
each programming language has decided to handle this, and there’s no clear
consensus:

```
$ # Modulus sign is:
$
$ curl 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Modulo_operation&action=edit&section=1' \
    | egrep -o 'Divisor|Dividend|Always positive|Closest to zero|Not defined|Implementation defined' \
    | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr

  67 Dividend
  42 Divisor
   7 Always positive
   4 Closest to zero
   2 Not defined
   2 Implementation defined
```

Some choose the sign of the left-hand operand, and some the right-hand
operand. Others don’t specify. For example, [*The C Programming Language*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628)
says:

> the sign of the result for % [is] machine-dependent for negative operands

Instead of making a particular choice for how to handle this, C just
returns whatever the particular hardware or compiler being used have chosen
to implement! This seems to have been standardized in more recent versions
of the C programming language standards.

If you want to get a particular version in Ruby, there are two different
methods you could call, [`modulo` aka `%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Numeric.html#method-i-modulo), and [`remainder`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Numeric.html#method-i-remainder),
with different behaviour on negative numbers:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> -7.modulo(3)
=> 2
irb(main):002:0> -7.remainder(3)
=> -1
```

In other languages that don’t have built-in methods for this, you may end
up using `%` twice to get the desired sign.